# Facebook Javascript SDK Audience Network Error 1003

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-audience-network

I just created an app on facebook to use Audience Network. I want to monetize my website. I placed the code on my site exactly as it appears in the github docs for banner display ads.

I included the SDK in the page exactly as it appears in this doc (replaced with my APP ID)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

And the code I'm using for the ad placement is taken exactly from facebook's github repo.

When I load the page I get an error in the console: 
`"Audience Network error (1003) SDK version not supported".` No ads are showing up.

Made a little test page so you guys can see what I'm talking about. Notice how the like and share buttons work (meaning the SDK works correctly if I'm not mistaken?)
https://somiibo.com/app/ads/sidebar/ad1.html

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1490948314307293',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
    <div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
    <h3>Facebook Audience Network for Mobile Web</h3>
  <hr/>
  <h3>Banner Demo (300 x 250)</h3>
  <br/>
  <div style="display:none; position: relative;">
    <iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var data = {
        placementid: '1490948314307293_1490949464307178',
        format: '300x250',
        testmode: false,
        onAdLoaded: function(element) {
          console.log('Audience Network ad loaded');
          element.style.display = 'block';
        },
        onAdError: function(errorCode, errorMessage) {
          console.log('Audience Network error (' + errorCode + ') ' + errorMessage);
        }
      };
      (function(w,l,d,t){var a=t();var b=d.currentScript||(function(){var c=d.getElementsByTagName('script');return c[c.length-1];})();var e=b.parentElement;e.dataset.placementid=data.placementid;var f=function(v){try{return v.document.referrer;}catch(e){}return'';};var g=function(h){var i=h.indexOf('/',h.indexOf('://')+3);if(i===-1){return h;}return h.substring(0,i);};var j=[l.href];var k=false;var m=false;if(w!==w.parent){var n;var o=w;while(o!==n){var h;try{m=m||(o.$sf&&o.$sf.ext);h=o.location.href;}catch(e){k=true;}j.push(h||f(n));n=o;o=o.parent;}}var p=l.ancestorOrigins;if(p){if(p.length>0){data.domain=p[p.length-1];}else{data.domain=g(j[j.length-1]);}}data.url=j[j.length-1];data.channel=g(j[0]);data.width=screen.width;data.height=screen.height;data.pixelratio=w.devicePixelRatio;data.placementindex=w.ADNW&&w.ADNW.Ads?w.ADNW.Ads.length:0;data.crossdomain=k;data.safeframe=!!m;var q={};q.iframe=e.firstElementChild;var r='https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/web/?sdk=5.3';for(var s in data){q[s]=data[s];if(typeof(data[s])!=='function'){r+='&'+s+'='+encodeURIComponent(data[s]);}}q.iframe.src=r;q.tagJsInitTime=a;q.rootElement=e;q.events=[];w.addEventListener('message',function(u){if(u.source!==q.iframe.contentWindow){return;}u.data.receivedTimestamp=t();if(this.sdkEventHandler){this.sdkEventHandler(u.data);}else{this.events.push(u.data);}}.bind(q),false);q.tagJsIframeAppendedTime=t();w.ADNW=w.ADNW||{};w.ADNW.Ads=w.ADNW.Ads||[];w.ADNW.Ads.push(q);w.ADNW.init&&w.ADNW.init(q);})(window,location,document,Date.now||function(){return+new Date;});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbadnw.js" async></script>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <h3>Banner Demo (320 x 50)</h3>
  <br/>
  <div style="display:none; position: relative;">
    <iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var data = {
        placementid: '1490948314307293_1490949464307178',
        format: '320x50',
        testmode: false,
        onAdLoaded: function(element) {
          console.log('Audience Network ad loaded');
          element.style.display = 'block';
        },
        onAdError: function(errorCode, errorMessage) {
          console.log('Audience Network error (' + errorCode + ') ' + errorMessage);
        }
      };
      (function(w,l,d,t){var a=t();var b=d.currentScript||(function(){var c=d.getElementsByTagName('script');return c[c.length-1];})();var e=b.parentElement;e.dataset.placementid=data.placementid;var f=function(v){try{return v.document.referrer;}catch(e){}return'';};var g=function(h){var i=h.indexOf('/',h.indexOf('://')+3);if(i===-1){return h;}return h.substring(0,i);};var j=[l.href];var k=false;var m=false;if(w!==w.parent){var n;var o=w;while(o!==n){var h;try{m=m||(o.$sf&&o.$sf.ext);h=o.location.href;}catch(e){k=true;}j.push(h||f(n));n=o;o=o.parent;}}var p=l.ancestorOrigins;if(p){if(p.length>0){data.domain=p[p.length-1];}else{data.domain=g(j[j.length-1]);}}data.url=j[j.length-1];data.channel=g(j[0]);data.width=screen.width;data.height=screen.height;data.pixelratio=w.devicePixelRatio;data.placementindex=w.ADNW&&w.ADNW.Ads?w.ADNW.Ads.length:0;data.crossdomain=k;data.safeframe=!!m;var q={};q.iframe=e.firstElementChild;var r='https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/web/?sdk=5.3';for(var s in data){q[s]=data[s];if(typeof(data[s])!=='function'){r+='&'+s+'='+encodeURIComponent(data[s]);}}q.iframe.src=r;q.tagJsInitTime=a;q.rootElement=e;q.events=[];w.addEventListener('message',function(u){if(u.source!==q.iframe.contentWindow){return;}u.data.receivedTimestamp=t();if(this.sdkEventHandler){this.sdkEventHandler(u.data);}else{this.events.push(u.data);}}.bind(q),false);q.tagJsIframeAppendedTime=t();w.ADNW=w.ADNW||{};w.ADNW.Ads=w.ADNW.Ads||[];w.ADNW.Ads.push(q);w.ADNW.init&&w.ADNW.init(q);})(window,location,document,Date.now||function(){return+new Date;});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbadnw.js" async></script>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey Ian, welcome to SO. Please include code snippets when possible. You'll get more responses if you don't rely on us to chase down your links. But +1 on the link to the demo site.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace sdk `https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/web/?sdk=5.3` to `https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/web/?sdk=5.5`
I hope I can help you.